# C#, how to get WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name from Azure application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are trying to deploy our legacy webforms app to azure.
Our application security model is based around Window Active Directory.

1 For a site hosted in Azure, what is the equivalent c# code for this:
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
This articles demonstrates using "OWIN" middleware.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp. Am i on the right track?

2 Since my localhost isn't hosted on Azure (it' running under IIS Express), what's an alternative to using this everywhere:
if (debugMode or localhost) then WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
else Azure-AD-equivalent-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For a site hosted in Azure, what is the equivalent c# code for this: WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

It seems that you using the Azure WebApp service, if it is that case, **unfortunately, we can't use the Windows Authentication in azure WebApp service.**

Maybe Azure Web Sites Azure Actice Directy is the best option. [Sync from AD to Azure Actice Directy](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-sync-on-premises-active-directory-to-azure-active-directory-with-azure-ad-connect/) is also quite easy to setup. Then use [Azure Easy Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-websites-easy-authentication-and-authorization-with-chris-gillum/) to do that.

If you still want to use the Windows Authentication, I recommand that you could use the [Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/overview). You need to join the VM to your AD.

Comment: Yes, using Azure WebApp service. And the sync from ActiveDirectory to Azure Active Directory has been completed.

Comment: The code at 1:43 was useful. We are going to use this: var claimsPrinciple = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal; var userEmail = claimsPrinciple.Identity.Name; We will identify the user by email instead of domainName.